# Calling a Javascript Function Twice

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to call a function twice in different functions. The first function creates two buttons and adds an `onclick` event. I need to do this multiple times, but it's not working! Here's my Javascript:

```
// PLAYER INFO
var playerHP = 100;
var playerAt = 10;
var playerDef = 0;
var gold = 0;
//ENEMY FROG INFO
var enemy = 'FROG';
var enemyHP = 50;
var enemyAt = 5;
var loot = 5;
//FOF
function fof() {
  var fight = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var t = document.createTextNode("FIGHT!");
  fight.appendChild(t);
  fight.id='attack';
  document.body.appendChild(fight);
  document.getElementById('attack').addEventListener('click', attack);

  var or = document.createElement("P");
  var g = document.createTextNode("or");
  or.appendChild(g);
  document.body.appendChild(or);

  var flee = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var p = document.createTextNode("FLEE!");
  flee.appendChild(p);
  flee.id = 'flee';
  document.body.appendChild(flee);
  document.getElementById('playerflee').addEventListener('click', flee);
}
//ENEMY ATTACK
function enemyAttack() {
  playerHP = playerHP - enemyAt;
  var enemyFight = document.createElement('P');
  var t = document.createTextNode('The enemy attacked you! You now have '+ playerHP + ' HP left!');
  enemyFight.appendChild(t);
  enemyFight.id = 'enemyattack';
  document.body.appendChild(enemyFight);
  fof();
}
//FIGHT
function attack() {
  enemyHP = enemyHP - playerAt;
  var playerAttack = document.createElement('P');
  var t = document.createTextNode('You attacked the enemy! It has ' + enemyHP + ' HP left!');
  playerAttack.appendChild(t);
  playerAttack.id = 'attack';
  document.body.appendChild(playerAttack);
  enemyAttack();
}
//FLEE
function flee() {
  var spare = document.createElement('P');
  var t = document.createTextNode('You ran away! You gained 0 loot!');
  spare.appendChild(t);
  spare.id = 'playerflee';
  document.body.appendChild(spare);
}
//Enemy Spawn
function spawn(){
    var p = document.createElement("P");
    var t = document.createTextNode("A wild FROG appeared! He has " + enemyHP + ' HP and ' + enemyAt+ ' attack! Will you...');
    p.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
    fof();
}
```

As you can see, I call `fof()` twice- once in `spawn()` and once in `enemyAttack()`. I know it works in the first, as it works when I first call it then. However, when I come to the second, `enemyAttack()`, it doesn't work! Any help would be appreciated.

Also, my HTML is just a button with an `onclick` event calling `spawn()`

Comment: What's with the text based frog-violence? Second time I've seen this today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID's are unique, you can only have one single element in the document with any given ID. Knowing this, `document.getElementById('attack')` only returns the first element in the DOM, every single time.

As you already have the element, there's no need to look it up

```
function fof() {
    var fight = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t     = document.createTextNode("FIGHT!");

    fight.className = 'attack';
    fight.addEventListener('click', attack);

    fight.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(fight);



    ...
```

Comment: I'm going to say this very excitedly, as I don't get to say it often when it comes to Javascript. IT WORKED! Thanks!